# How to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^N \log(1+a_i x_i^2) \text{ s.t.} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i= 1,x_i \geq 0$

Tags: optimization

How to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^N \log(1+a_i x_i^2) s.t. \sum_{i=1}^N x_i= 1,x_i \geq 0$?   The objective function is non-convex. Is there any tutorial or solution about how to deal with such problem ? Thank you!

Comment: lagrange multipliers

Comment: Thanks! But I can not solve the equation as there are quadratic terms in each equation.